# How to get all orders in saleor api?

Tags: saleor

I have such user that create some order and I attach user some permission like Order managment in saleor admin panel. I logged in app in localhost:3000 using such user. Here is my response from CurrentCustomer.

```
{
    "data": {
        "me": {
            "id": "VXNlcjoyMDg0NTEwNTU1",
            "permissionGroups": [
                {
                    "id": "R3JvdXA6MTM=",
                    "name": "Orders management",
                    "userCanManage": true
                }
            ],
            "userPermissions": [
                {
                    "code": "HANDLE_CHECKOUTS",
                    "name": "Handle checkouts"
                },
                {
                    "code": "HANDLE_PAYMENTS",
                    "name": "Handle payments"
                },
                {
                    "code": "HANDLE_TAXES",
                    "name": "Handle taxes"
                },
                {
                    "code": "IMPERSONATE_USER",
                    "name": "Impersonate user."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_APPS",
                    "name": "Manage apps"
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_CHANNELS",
                    "name": "Manage channels."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_CHECKOUTS",
                    "name": "Manage checkouts"
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_DISCOUNTS",
                    "name": "Manage sales and vouchers."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_GIFT_CARD",
                    "name": "Manage gift cards."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_MENUS",
                    "name": "Manage navigation."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_OBSERVABILITY",
                    "name": "Manage observability"
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_ORDERS",
                    "name": "Manage orders."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_ORDERS_IMPORT",
                    "name": "Manage orders import."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_PAGES",
                    "name": "Manage pages."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_PAGE_TYPES_AND_ATTRIBUTES",
                    "name": "Manage page types and attributes."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_PLUGINS",
                    "name": "Manage plugins"
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_PRODUCTS",
                    "name": "Manage products."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_PRODUCT_TYPES_AND_ATTRIBUTES",
                    "name": "Manage product types and attributes."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_SETTINGS",
                    "name": "Manage settings."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_SHIPPING",
                    "name": "Manage shipping."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_STAFF",
                    "name": "Manage staff."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_TAXES",
                    "name": "Manage taxes"
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_TRANSLATIONS",
                    "name": "Manage translations."
                },
                {
                    "code": "MANAGE_USERS",
                    "name": "Manage customers."
                }
            ],
            "defaultShippingAddress": null,
            "email": "artur.demenskiy@everget.co",
            "firstName": "Artur",
            "lastName": "Demenskiy",
            "dateJoined": "2024-02-01T08:26:56.144104+00:00"
        }
    },
    "extensions": {
        "cost": {
            "requestedQueryCost": 3,
            "maximumAvailable": 50000
        }
    }
}
```

I run query that get all orders, but I have some problems. Why is it ? I already gave him permission.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph8rI.png)

here is my handler

```
import type { OperationContext } from '@vercel/commerce/api/operations'
import { GraphQLFetcherResult } from '@vercel/commerce/api'
import type { Provider, SaleorConfig } from '..'
import * as Query from '../../utils/queries'

type ReturnType = {
  orders: any[]
}

export default function getAllOrdersOperation({
  commerce,
}: OperationContext<Provider>) {
  async function getAllOrders({
    query = Query.OrderMany,
    variables = {
      first: 10,
      filter: {
        customer: 'VXNlcjoyMDg0NTEwNTU1',
      },
    },
    config,
  }: {
    query?: string
    variables?: any
    config?: Partial<SaleorConfig>
    preview?: boolean
  } = {}): Promise<ReturnType> {
    const { fetch, locale, locales = ['en-US'] } = commerce.getConfig(config)

    console.log({ variables, locale })

    try {
      const { data }: GraphQLFetcherResult = await fetch(
        query,
        { variables },
        {
          ...(locale && {
            'Accept-Language': locale,
          }),
        }
      )
      console.log('hello', { data })
      const orders = data?.orders?.edges?.map(({ node: order }: any) => order)
      return { orders }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error fetching orders', err)
      return { orders: [] }
    }
  }

  return getAllOrders
}
```

and here is my graphQl query

```
import * as fragment from '../fragments'

export const OrderMany = /* GraphQL */ `
  query OrderMany($first: Int = 10, $filter: OrderFilterInput) {
    orders(first: $first, filter: $filter) {
      ...OrderConnection
    }
  }
  ${fragment.OrderConnection}
`


export const OrderConnection = /* GraphQL */ `
  fragment OrderConnection on OrderCountableConnection {
    pageInfo {
      hasNextPage
      hasPreviousPage
    }
    edges {
      node {
        id
        number
        status
        isShippingRequired
        canFinalize
        created
        customerNote
        paymentStatus
        userEmail
        isPaid
      }
    }
  }
`
```

I drop already customer id or email but it doesn`t work

```
variables = {
      first: 10,
      filter: {
        customer: 'VXNlcjoyMDg0NTEwNTU1',
      },
    },
```

Comment: I got To access this path, you need one of the following permissions: MANAGE_ORDERS'

Comment: Please do not post error messages via screenshot.
Regarding the question, did you authorize user? I'm not js expert, but just from glance I cannot see authorization part.

Comment: kadewu, thank you just need to put  auth jwt token inside this query 

  const { data }: GraphQLFetcherResult = await fetch(
        query,
        { variables },
        {
          ...(locale && {
            'Accept-Language': locale,
          }),
        }
      )